# generate a random number in powershell from a range but exclude 1

Tags: powershell, random

I want to generate a random number from a range (lets say 1 to 3) but exclude from that range specific number in variable X

So I got this code

```
get-random -inputobject (1..4) | where {$_ -notin $X}
```

this indeed generate a random number between 1 and 3 but when the generate number is equal to the number in X, it returns nothing.

How can I force it to run again when it happens so I always get a number, don't matter how many tries it takes?

Comment: `do..while` can help you with that, also, `-notin` doesnt do what you think it does. even logically thinking (not in terms of powershell syntax) you are looking for not equals operator

Comment: you mean do.. while {$generatednumber -ne $X}?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to remove the items you want to exclude before calling `Get-Random`:

```
$InputRange = 1..10
$Exclude = 3,4,5

$RandomRange = $InputRange | Where-Object { $Exclude -notcontains $_ }

Get-Random -InputObject $RandomRange
```